# Creating constructor for hashset and hashmap

Tags: java

I have the following data structures created..

```
private Scanner scan;
HashSet<String> hset = new HashSet<String>();
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hmap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>(); 
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I am confused on how to create a constructor to initialize these. I have the scanner I am pretty sure but some help with the others would be great.

```
public SpellChecker(){
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    hset = new HashSet<String>();
    hmap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

}
```

Comment: Move everything you have in the first code block inside the `SpellChecker` constructor?

Comment: @mckuok I have a certain spot where I declare them, then I have to initialize them in the constructor

Comment: can you clarify what you meant by "initialize"?

Comment: @mckuok Actually see my updated code in the question. I think I have to do something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you can define those variables as class member variables, so that you can use the variable in the scope that you want (with the right [access modifier](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm) that is )

```
public class SpellChecker {
    private Scanner scan;
    private HashSet<String> hset;
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hmap;
    private ArrayList<Integer> myList;

    public SpellChecker(){
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        hset = new HashSet<String>();
        hmap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

}
```